# OrderBy Linq.Expression as parameter = (Of Func(Of T,IComparable)) to perform LinqToEntity is not working

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework-4, lambda

I'd like to get this working:

DBSet constructor:

```
dbset = DataContext().[Set](Of T)()
```

Call: (Count & Page are used for pagination, so Count = 20 and Page = 1 for example, for the first 20 values). Sorting should be by name

```
LeverancierService.GetLeveranciers(Function(el) el.Name, Count, Page)
```

Equivalent in c#:
    LeverancierService.GetLeveranciers(el=> el.Name, Count, Page)

Method that gives an error (parameters shown above):

```
 Public Overridable Function GetAllPaged(orderby As Expression(Of Func(Of T, IComparable)), ByVal Count As Integer, ByVal Page As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of T)
      Return dbset.OrderBy(orderby).Skip((Page - 1) * Count).Take(Count).ToList()
 End Function
```

Already tried changing it to this, but it gives the same error:

```
 Public Overridable Function GetAllPaged(Of TOrderBy)(orderby As Expression(Of Func(Of T, TOrderBy)), ByVal Count As Integer, ByVal Page As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of T)
        Return dbset.OrderBy(orderby).Skip((Page - 1) * Count).Take(Count).ToList()
 End Function
```

Error:

```
 Unable to cast the type 'System.String' to type 'System.IComparable'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.
```

Any idea how to do this?

Extra info:

I'm in a DDD-layered application, so the parameter should stay the same as the called method is an overridden interface (eg. if i change this, i have to do this for 200 times or so, because it's in VB.Net and not in C# (= 1 change)  )

Comment: Can you add more data about your dbset? how is your dbset defined? like this? : DataContext.Set(Of TEntity)?

Comment: Private ReadOnly dbset As IDbSet(Of T)

Comment: dbset = DataContext().[Set](Of T)()

Answer (score 1):

*Here is my sample. I hope it solves your problem:*

If type of your **dbset is not defined**:

```
Public Function Test(Of TEntity As Class, TKey) _
    (keySelector As Expression(Of Func(Of TEntity, TKey))) As IList(Of TEntity)
    Return DataContext.Set(Of TEntity).OrderBy(keySelector).ToList
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Repository.Test(Function(obj As MyEntity) obj.Name)
```

If type of your **dbset is defined**, you can use this other sample:

```
    Public Function Test2(Of TKey) _
        (keySelector As Expression(Of Func(Of MyEntity, TKey))) _
        As IList(Of MyEntity)
        Return DataContext.Set(Of MyEntity).OrderBy(keySelector).ToList
    End Function
```

Used like this:

```
Repository.Test(Function(obj) obj.Name)
```

Comment: Weird. My second solution of the function (according to me) was totally similar. Have you tested it?

Comment: It was copied from one of my own projects, I'll update my answer soon and include actual code from my project.